# Edit .htaccess with Wordpress Plugin API?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write a wordpress plugin that requires changing the .htaccess file. How do I do that in PHP. I have seen this done before with other plugins but, I can not figure out how it is done. Thanks!

Comment: This is bad practice

Comment: I will ask permission and it will add on not change around

Comment: I have the code that will be added to the .htaccess so no

Comment: @gmaniac what if the purpose of the plugin was, for example, to help the user optimize their wordpress site? - to add file cache rules.

Comment: @digout I think I did not clarify very well, the whole practice of changing the `.htaccess` with a plugin imo is bad practice. There are plugins out there that alter the `.htaccess`, who are good and helpful. I don't trust a lot of plugins so I don't like leaving my `.htaccess` file writable. This is also the difference from technical and non-technical users. Things like this I do myself, whereas a user that has minimal knowledge, a plugin like this is super helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function in wordpress to update the `.htaccess` file is `insert_with_markers` it takes three parameters.

```
insert_with_markers ( string $filename, string $marker, array|string $insertion )
```

in following this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160709162037/http://wordpress.think-bowl.com/development/safely-update-htaccess-plugin/) you could write something like this

```
// Get path to main .htaccess for WordPress
$htaccess = get_home_path().".htaccess";

$lines = array();
$lines[] = "RewriteBase /foobar";

insert_with_markers($htaccess, "MyPlugin", $lines);
```

That would look like this in the your `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN MyPlugin
RewriteBase /foobar
# END MyPlugin
```

Here is a link to wordpress' documentation of that function

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/